# Manipulating An Equation into A Workable Form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, plane-curves

The question asks me to find the arc length of 
$$y= (x-x^2)^{1/2} + \sin^{-1}(x^{1/2})$$
I know I need to take the derivative:
$$\frac{1-2x}{2(x-x^2)^{1/2}} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/2}}$$
I've tried manipulating it to simplify it, since I need some equation that is easy to square, but I've gotten nowhere. I tried getting a common denominator but that didn't really help. 
I also tried rationalizing the denominator but got stuck as well.

Please help!

Ok, sorry! The derivative of $$\sin^{-1}(x^{1/2})$$ should be $$\frac{1}{2(x)^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}}$$
That makes more sense!

Comment: This may look dirty, but believe on differentiating and squaring and adding 1 and taking root, it will be easy to integrate. Why? because the person who made this question did back working.

Answer (score 4):

The second expression in your derivative (the derivative of the arcsin term) is incorrect as you need to use the chain rule.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})=\frac{d}{d(\sqrt{x})}\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x})\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

So the differential should be

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-2x}{2(x-x^2)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{2x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}}\\=\frac{1-2x}{2x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}}+\frac{1}{2x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}}\\=\frac{2(1-x)}{2x^{1/2}(1-x)^{1/2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}$$

I will leave it to you to do the rest.